# Overloading operator= of user defined type with unique_ptr data member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

I have a user defined class that has a `std::unique_ptr` member. I am trying to overload the assignment operator to new an object of the same type to the `unique_ptr` member or assign the value to the `ptr` value.

```
class object
{
    public:
    // POD types

    object& operator=(const object& _obj);

    std::unique_ptr<baseClass> ptr;
}
```

I've tried using:

```
std::unique_ptr::swap()
```

but the swap function is non-const so I attempted assigning the the result of:

```
std::unique_ptr::get()
```

to the `ptr` and then calling:

```
std::unique_ptr::release()
```

but release also is non const, so I cannot guarantee that `ptr` will be destructed correctly since the old `ptr` will still have ownership. Alas, `operator=()` for `unique_ptr` does not accept a non-const reference to another `unique_ptr` so I have opted to make the operator= as so for my class.

```
object& object::operator=(const object& _obj)
{
    //POD types use operator= as normal
    ptr.reset(nullptr);

    return *this;
}
```

And just call a `setPtr()` method later on to set the `ptr`. I wanted to just detect the type and just assign the `ptr` using:

```
ptr.reset(new detectedType );
```

but the consensus all over Stack Overflow and my preferred search engine is that detecting types like this would be a design flaw. My question is: am I overlooking something simple and is there a better way to overload the assignment operator for user defined types that have a `unique_ptr` member?

**Before post edit:**
   I changed the parameter to `object&` rather than `const object&` and it worked. Is this a good way to correct this issue or should I be trying to work with only const references to the other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: am I overlooking something simple and is there a better way to overload the assignment operator for user defined types that have a unique_ptr member?

There is indeed. This breaks down to understanding what smart pointers in `C++` do. Usually you use a `std::unique_ptr` if there will be one and only one reference to your object. This is the reason why `std_unique_ptr`s are neither copy-constructable nor copy-assignable. If you manually create two copies of a `std::unique_ptr` as you describe in you post by using `ptr.get()` you will end up in an invalid state, because as soon as one copy leaves scope, the `std::unique_ptr` destructor will also destruct the object it points to, leaving the other `std::unqiue_ptr` in an invalid state (it points to a freed memory location). So if there might be several references to your object you should probably use `std::shared_ptr` instead.

In your examples the question is what do you want to achieve?

If you want your assignment operator such that after calling `a = b`, `a.ptr` and `b.ptr` point to the exact same object (i.e. store the same pointer) use a shared pointer. You should definitely NOT use a unique pointer in this case, as calling the destructor for `a` or `b` would destruct the object pointed to, leaving `a` or `b` in an invalid state.

If you want that after calling `a = b`, `a.ptr` points to independent copy of `*(b.ptr)` you can indeed use a unique pointer and implement you assignment operator like this (provided `baseClass` is copy construable) :

```
object& object::operator=(const object& _obj)
{
    //POD types use operator= as normal
    ptr.reset(new baseClass(*_obj.ptr));

    return *this;
}
```

Note however that this only works if `baseClass` is `final` (unlikely considering the name...), i.e. `ptr` won't store pointers to objects of a derived class. Otherwise this results in [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/991425) as pointed out by BenVoigt.

Finally, it is generally expected that calling `a = b` does **not** change `b`. Therefore making the `ptr` member mutable and using `swap` sounds like a bad idea to me. If you want to achieve this behavior because of performance (or other) considerations, I would suggest to implement the move assignment operator instead

```
object& object::operator=(object&& _obj)
{
    //POD types use operator= as normal
    ptr = std::move(_obj.ptr);

    return *this;
}
```

and call `a = std::move(b)`, which makes clear that `b` might end up in a different state.

Comment: Unfortunately `new baseClass(*_obj.ptr)` suffers from slicing.  One needs a polymorphic "clone" system to make a copy which has the correct runtime type.

Comment: @BenVoigt Correct. I didn't quite think about the implications of the name `baseClass`. I updated my answer to mention this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the `mutable` keyword.  If you declare `ptr` as `mutable`, you are indicating that even when an instance of your class is semantically const, it must perform non-const operations on a particular data member.  Declare your class as follows, and you should be able to implement your original idea of using `swap`:

```
class object
{
    public:
    // POD types

    object& operator=(const object& _obj);

    mutable std::unique_ptr<baseClass> ptr;
}
```

Comment: This of course depends on the purpose of `ptr`, in general however I would strongly argue against this approach, because you would generally expect that `a=b` does **not** change `b`. See my answer for details.

Comment: `mutable` will get this code past the compiler, but it still won't make it right.  C++ deprecated silent-ownership-stealing `unique_ptr<T>` (it was called `auto_ptr<T>` at the time) for a good reason.